# dc.js charts, how to get the intersection of multiple filters

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am wondering if anyone can help me with getting the intersection of multiple filters. 
For example:

if I have following:

```
var ndx = crossfilter([
    {id: 1, arrayVals: [1, 2]},
    {id: 2, arrayVals: [2, 3]},
    {id: 3, arrayVals: [1, 2, 3]}
]);
```

how do I get items with arrayVals that have 1 and 3? And how do I get the filter value onclick?
As far as I know, within a dc chart the filtering is "OR" and between dc charts, the filtering is "AND".

Thanks Millions,

Anney

Comment: You are right, each dc.js chart ordinarily produces an OR filter over the selected items in a chart, and crossfilter combines the dimensions' filters with AND. Are you talking about using a single chart, e.g. a pie chart or bar chart, to produce an AND filter? Is this chart using a [tag / array dimension](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays)?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your quick reply.  Yes, I am trying to use a single chart to produce an AND filter and yes this chart is using a array dimension.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this behavior is baked into crossfilter - you can't have it aggregate using array-keys, but filter using regular keys. And I think you'd need regular keys to do this - crossfilter has effectively split each row into as many rows as there are keys, and it doesn't really have any way to work with the original rows any more. I don't have too much experience with this feature, and I could be wrong about this.